# What alternative materials (Non-silicon) are available for semiconductors?

Tags: transistors, semiconductors, materials

I'm trying to construct a simple logic gate with a transistor, but I don't want to use silicon as the semiconductor. **What other materials are available to construct transistors with?** Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why? And are you planning on doping your own transistors? That'd be quite tough to say the least. The other common materials are germanium and gallium, though the choice more so depends on your use. Silicon is pretty stable and fast for most uses.

Comment: This question is *very* suitable for any modern search engine.

Comment: If you would read a textbook about semiconductors you would learn what properties makes a material a possible semiconductor. We can list all the materials that are used as semiconductors but that does not mean these are the only ones that can be used as semiconductors.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_semiconductor_materials

Comment: Unobtanium-234 is also a good choice.

Comment: Why not try vacuum tubes (valves)?  No silicon there (except possibly small amounts in an alloy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically speaking, your choice is limited to germanium transistors. These are slower than silicon and have more leakage, and they are pretty much unavailable except on eBay (for 5 to 20 bucks each).

GaAs, Gallium Arsenide, is also occasionally used, but these are rare, even more expensive than germanium, and are typically used in very high-frequency (GHz plus) linear applications.

Answer (score 1):

Silicon-germanium is used for very high frequencies.

You can buy [Gallium Nitride FETs](http://epc-co.com/epc/Portals/0/epc/documents/datasheets/EPC2035_datasheet.pdf) fairly cheaply (about $1 each), albeit generally in fairly inconvenient packages for the tinkerer.

[image]

As they are aimed at power applications they are not ideal for logic gates unless you have some very strange requirements. Also pay attention to the high gate leakage.